# Place tmux configuration in a different folder

Tags: tmux

I have my tmux configuration in `"$DOTFILES"/tmux/tmux.conf` and I'd like to know if this is a correct way of using that configuration without copying or symlinking it to the `$HOME` directory.

In my `.zshenv` I have:

```
export TMUX_DIR="$DOTFILES"/tmux
export TMUX="$TMUX_DIR"/tmux.conf
```

In my `.zshrc` I have:

```
alias tmux=tmux -f "$TMUX"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, that's perfectly acceptable.  However, there's no "magic" in the `TMUX_DIR` or `TMUX` variables (`tmux` doesn't use them), so you could just as easily shorten it to:

```
alias tmux='tmux -f "$DOTFILES/tmux/tmux.conf"'
```

You might also consider using `~/.config` as your `$DOTFILES` directory.  As of Tmux version 3.1, you don't even need a `-f` if you use `~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf`.  And quite a few other modern tools (e.g. the `fish` shell, `htop`, `bat`) also use that by default.

I'm sure your goal in using a separate `$DOTFILES` is to keep `~` clean and have an easier way to version control your configs.  That's why `~/.config` is becoming the standard (under XDG, Systemd, and more) for that.

Comment: Oh wow they finally use the XDG_CONFIG_HOME folder, now that I've gotten around that... I've actually had trouble with setting the TMUX variable. My tmux configuration was getting overwritten. Now I'm not using it and when I echo the variable in the terminal it has output `/tmp/tmux-1000/default,29503,0`

Comment: @ajr-dev Re: XDG_CONFIG_HOME, yes, but unfortunately I seem to recall that they hardcoded it to `~/.config` rather than reading the XDG variable (or `systemd-path user-configuration`).  As for the `TMUX` variable, I guess I misspoke -- It looks like it is used internally, but doesn't seem like it should be set by the user, right?