# Tmux doesn't read `~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf` by default, so where?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tmux, dot-files

As title. I always do things on macOS, but now I have to learn some Virtual Machine and have installed Ubuntu 20.04. On macOS I put all dotfiles inside the folder `~/.config/`. I did the same on Ubuntu, but it didn't work. Now I have to run

```
tmux source ~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf
```

everytime I enter a session, or I will not be able to use those keybindings. So where should I put this config file? My intuition told me that I would need to create a symlink to the default path, which I don't know, to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the two answers with the traditional tmux config locations, tmux 3.1 and later *does* support `~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf`, although it's not mentioned in the man page.  See the [release notes here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tmux/tmux/3.1/CHANGES). That's why it works for you on MacOS.

However, the [Ubuntu 20.04 repo](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=tmux) looks like it's only at 3.0.

If you can run 21.04 or later in your VM, it should have an appropriate tmux version, and `~/.config/tmux/tmux.conf` should be automatically handled for you.

If you are stuck on Ubuntu 20.04 for LTS reasons, then you can fall back to the symlink option, or use the `-f` option as in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/662972/432493).

Comment: Wow, I just checked the version info. on macOS and Ubuntu, and the results are `3.2a`, `3.0a`, respectively, exactly like you said!

Comment: @Niing, I decided to open a pull request suggesting the addition of this path in the manual page, so that we don't have to look at the changelog or source code and it was [accepted](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/pull/3023#issuecomment-1006369857) by one of the maintainers, probably it will be easier to find this information in the next releases of tmux.

Comment: Thanks @dandev486.  That will definitely help educate more people on the availability of this feature.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [tmux man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/tmux.1.html#description) the default location for the config files in Ubuntu is `/etc/tmux.conf` and `~/.tmux.conf`

> By default, tmux loads the system
> configuration file from /etc/tmux.conf, if present, then looks for a user
> configuration file at ~/.tmux.conf.

Comment: OK, I'm stupid. My `ln -s` command contains `~`  in it. I was thinking about why I did the same but it didn't work as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> By default, tmux loads the system configuration file from `/etc/tmux.conf`, if present, then looks for a user configuration file at `~/.tmux.conf`.

More information can be found on the command [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html).

This is actually the default behaviour until tmux 3.0, apparently, even though it is undocumented on the manual page, the aforementioned path was added, as can be seen, when comparing the source code for [tmux 3.0 and 3.1](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/compare/3.0...3.1#diff-0462e381b2fb3286568215681c8983490a37ac9ae0f0c5ee304df7fa6426d4afR16).

=====

[EDIT] The information will now be available at the manual page of a later version, I've made the suggestion and [it was accepted](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/pull/3023#issuecomment-1006369857) by one of the maintainers, it has been commited to the [master branch](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/e5e4df7a2241298b7ea3ba77b5fe1fdef6df0e08).

Comment: OK, I'm stupid. My `ln -s` command contains `~`  in it. I was thinking about why I did the same but it didn't work as your answer.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why I don't have to add a symlink to `~/.tmux.conf` on macOS?

Comment: I don't own a mac, to be a hundred percent sure, honestly! However, the `~/.tmux.conf` file in all my linux machines is a regular file, not a symbolic link.

Comment: The intent of using the symbolic link, it to keep a single copy of the actual file, but still have it accessible from where tmux read it by default. Notice that this is due to your preference of storing the configuration file somewhere else. It is not a matter of "why I don't have to", is just a matter of how you chose to organize your configuration files.

Comment: It seems like I was persuaded by someone that it's would be a good idea to put all configs under `~/.config` and put a symlink back to `~` when something doesn't work :/

Comment: It is not a bad idea storing your configuration files in a central location, it makes it easier to backup them and to know where things are. It is just not the default, location for tmux and you have to either manually close this gap in order to organize your computer in your own way, or otherwise add the `tmux source` line in a initialization script such as bashrc, for instance.

Comment: Last but not least, the correct command line is `tmux source-file`, not `tmux source` (man page for tmux 3.1c)